# Regex-driven while-loop not looping properly

Tags: c++, regex

```
    ifstream infile("somefile.txt");
    char letter;
    infile >> noskipws >> letter;
    string word;
    word = letter;
    while(regex_match(word, regex("[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*", regex_constants::basic))){
        infile >> letter;
        word += letter;
    }
    if(regex_match(word, regex("[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*.", regex_constants::basic))){
        //Do stuff
    }
```

When I run this code and watch it in GDB, the while loop will execute exactly once, regardless of the text in the text file that `infile` is feeding `letter`. Then, it will skip the if-statement, as the if statement apparently returns false. Each run of this function should be having `word` holding the entire word at the current position of `infile`. Where is my regex failing? Or is it something else?

An example to clarify: A text file containing solely the words "words fail me" will have `word` contain just "wo" at the end of the function.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but at some point you need to consume the space or the `while` loop will match the first word, then stop matching since the next part starts with a space (or punctuation, or just non-[A-Za-z_]). And in your sample code in the `if`, there's a variable `recognized` that isn't declared anywhere...

Comment: @mathematical.coffee That's exactly how the loop is supposed to operate. Instead, `word` will never hold more than 2 characters at a time, and they will be any character.

Answer (score 1):

@MowDownJoe - I believe `std::regex` is `boost::regex`, but why are you playing around, assign a constant and test `regex_match()`. If it works fine, if not, `regex` is not functional in your compiled Lang.

Comment: you don't have to tag the user asking the question by using `@` when u post an answer. The user will be notified either way when an answer to his/her question is posted.

Comment: You can't say std::regex is boost::regex. If you use std::regex, you are getting your compiler vendor's *implementation* of std::regex, not the boost one. Also std::regex was modelled after boost::regex, there are some differences though.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are seeing is a result of a buggy implementation of std::regex. I tried an even simpler use of the same regex (see http://ideone.com/xuY2nD):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s = "He";
    if (regex_match(s, regex("[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*", regex_constants::basic))) {
        cout << "Match" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and it did not match - which it should have done. I then tried the same thing but using boost::regex and it works as expected.

From what I [read](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631) gcc versions < 4.9 do not have working std::regex support.

A few side pointers:

- Constructing regex instances can be expensive - you should not do it inside a loop as you have done. In fact if the function is called multiple times in your program and the regex is constant, then it would be better to declare a static const instance
- In any case, your logic would be much more efficient if you just checked the characters you add to your 'word' rather than keep re-matching the whole word. You know the characters you have added so far already match so no need to keep re-matching the whole string.
- The second regex match would also seem redundant - if the first one in the loop is working then the second must match

Answer (score 0):

From the boost doc's:

```
'The algorithm regex_match determines whether a given regular expression matches 
all of a given character sequence'
```

If your initial `word` was not matched, it never gets appended to.
Therefore, both the while and if fail.

Comment: Updated question with an example. I know how these lines of code SHOULD work. The question is, why are they behaving in the way that they actually are.

Comment: @MowDownJoe - Try it using `regex_constants::perl` and also verify the contents of `word` variable before the regex_match statement.

Comment: I should've clarified that I wasn't using Boost regex, but rather std::regex, compiled with -std=C++0x. Also, word has only the first character in the file prior to the first regex_match.